# One or more compilation references may be missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core

I just added Microsoft.AspNet.MVC to my project and used Html.RenderAction to render a partial view however on compile im getting this message : `One or more compilation references may be missing`.

Here us how the .csproj looks:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.18" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and the offending line `@Html.RenderAction("MenuItems")` MenuItems exists and has a MapRoute

I am using VSCode, so I may just not understand how to do a particular thing since it doesn't have the inbuilt project management that VStudio has.

Answer (score 0):

I added an old version of MVC to my project to get MVC.Html helpers. I didn't need to do this.

RenderAction is deprecated and so is Action.